# Problem in POST and PUT request, with axios, vuetify datatable, vuejs

Tags: vue.js, datatable, axios, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm trying to adapt a sample datatable from the vuetify website itself according to my needs by implementing axios to consume my api. The **GET AND DELETE** method is working perfectly, however I am very confused about the **POST AND PUT** method, I am using 2 models as a client and the relationship with the genre, follows part of the code:

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="clients"
      sort-by="firstName"
      class="elevation-2"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-icon medium>mdi-account-supervisor</v-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title> Clients</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider
            class="mx-4"
            inset
            vertical
          ></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn 
                color="blue" 
                dark class="mt-6 mb-4" 
                v-on="on"
                rounded
                ><v-icon medium>mdi-plus</v-icon>Add new</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>

              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-form>
                    <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.firstName" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.lastName" label="Last Name"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.email" label="E-Mail"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.phone" label="Phone"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.mobilePhone" label="Mobile Phone"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <!-- select options-->
                        <v-select
                          label='Gender'
                          v-model='editedItem.gender.name'
                          :items='genders'
                          item-value='name'
                          item-text='name'
                        >
                        </v-select>
                      </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                  </v-form>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="error" rounded @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="primary" rounded @click="save">Save</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
        <v-icon
          small
          color="green"
          class="mr-2"
          @click="editItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-pencil
        </v-icon>
        <v-icon
          small
          color="red"
          @click="deleteItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-delete
        </v-icon>

      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Client from '../../services/clients';
import Gender from '../../services/genders';

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'First Name',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'firstName',
        },
        { text: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName' },
        { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
        { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' },
        { text: 'Mobile Phone', value: 'mobilePhone' },
        { text: 'Gender', value: 'gender.name' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false },
      ],
      clients: [],
      genders: [],
      errors: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        mobilePhone: '',
        gender: '',
      },
      defaultItem: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        mobilePhone: '',
        gender: '',
      },
    }),
    computed: {
      formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
      },
    },
    watch: {
      dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },
    methods: {
      initialize () {
        Client.list().then(response => {
          this.clients = response.data
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        Gender.list().then(response => {
          this.genders = response.data
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });

      },
      editItem (item) {
        axios.put('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/' + item.id)
          .then(response => {
            this.editedIndex = this.clients.indexOf(item)
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
            this.editedID = this.editedItem.id
            this.dialog = true
            this.response = response
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
      },

      deleteItem (item) {
        if (confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
          axios.delete('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/' + item.id)
          .then(response => {
            const index = this.clients.indexOf(item)
            this.deletedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
            this.deletedID = this.deletedItem.id
            this.clients.splice(index, 1);
            this.response = response
          }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        }
      },

      close () {
        this.dialog = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        }, 300)
      },

      save () {
        if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
          axios.post('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/')
          .then(response => {
            Object.assign(this.clients[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
            this.response = response.data
          }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        } else {
            this.clients.push(this.editedItem)
        }
        this.close()
      },

    },
  }
</script>
```

When opening the modal to add item, only when opening the select and modifying the genre this error already appears before even saving, as shown in the image:

When clicking on save it is saved only on the front, and when updating the page the record disappears, could someone give me a light?

**Update Edit.**

After some changes, I think I am closer to the solution but I came to the following obstacle, When saving the client item, the gender is stored empty.

[image] of console.log and the item saved in the front end but in the database the gender is empty

The file DataTable.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="clients"
      sort-by="firstName"
      class="elevation-2"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-icon medium>mdi-account-supervisor</v-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title> Clients</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider
            class="mx-4"
            inset
            vertical
          ></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn 
                color="blue" 
                dark class="mt-6 mb-4" 
                v-on="on"
                rounded
                ><v-icon medium>mdi-plus</v-icon>Add new</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>

              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-form>
                    <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.firstName" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.lastName" label="Last Name"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.email" label="E-Mail"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.phone" label="Phone"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.mobilePhone" label="Mobile Phone"></v-text-field>
                      </v-col>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                        <!-- select options-->
                        <v-select
                          label='Gender'
                          v-model='editedItem.gender'
                          :items='genders'
                          item-value='name'
                          item-text='name'
                        >
                        </v-select>
                      </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                  </v-form>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="error" rounded @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="primary" rounded @click="save">Save</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
        <v-icon
          small
          color="green"
          class="mr-2"
          @click="editItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-pencil
        </v-icon>
        <v-icon
          small
          color="red"
          @click="deleteItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-delete
        </v-icon>

      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Client from '../../services/clients';
import Gender from '../../services/genders';

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'First Name',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'firstName',
        },
        { text: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName' },
        { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
        { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' },
        { text: 'Mobile Phone', value: 'mobilePhone' },
        { text: 'Gender', value: 'gender.name' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false },
      ],
      clients: [],
      genders: [],
      errors: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        mobilePhone: '',
        gender: '',
      },
      defaultItem: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        mobilePhone: '',
        gender: '',
      },
    }),
    computed: {
      formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
      },
    },
    watch: {
      dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },
    methods: {
      initialize () {
        Client.list().then(response => {
          this.clients = response.data
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        Gender.list().then(response => {
          this.genders = response.data
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });

      },
      editItem (item) {
        axios.put('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/' + item.id)
          .then(response => {
            this.editedIndex = this.clients.indexOf(item)
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
            this.editedID = this.editedItem.id
            this.dialog = true
            this.response = response
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response)
        });
      },

      deleteItem (item) {
        if (confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
          axios.delete('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/' + item.id)
            .then(response => {
              const index = this.clients.indexOf(item)
              this.deletedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
              this.deletedID = this.deletedItem.id
              this.clients.splice(index, 1);
              this.response = response
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
              });
        }
      },

      close () {
        this.dialog = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        }, 300)
      },

      save () {
        if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
          Object.assign(this.clients[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
        } else {
            this.clients.push(this.editedItem)
            axios.post('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/', this.editedItem)
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
              }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error.response)
            });

        }
        this.close()
      },

    },
  }
</script>
```

Please would someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues. First, you aren't passing any data to your `PUT` and `POST` requests. They should look something like:

```js
editItem (item) {
  // YOU NEED TO PASS AN OBJECT TO THE PUT REQUEST         ▼▼HERE▼▼
  axios.put('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/' + item.id , item)
    .then(response => {
      // handle response...
    })
    .catch(err => { console.log(error) })
},
save () {
  if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
    // YOU NEED TO PASS AN OBJECT TO THE POST REQUEST  ▼▼HERE▼▼
    axios.post('http://192.168.26.130:3000/client/', this.editedItem)
      .then(response => {
        // handle response...
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(error) })
  } else { /* ... */ }
},
```

Second, under the hood, `<v-select>` uses a `v-for` to iterate over all of the options that are supposed to go into the dropdown menu. If this were a plain HTML `<select>` element, it would look something like this:

```html
<select name="gender">
  <option value="">Select a gender...</option>
  <option
    v-for="gender in genders"
    :key="gender"
    value="gender.value"
  >
    {{ gender.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Vuetify expects the array of genders to be in one of two formats, either an array of strings, or an array of objects with `text` and `value` properties:

```js
const genders = ['male', 'female', 'other']
// OR
const genders = [
  { value: 1, text: 'male' }, // `value` can be anything you want
  { value: 2, text: 'female' },
  { value: 3, text: 'other' },
]
```

Alternatively, if your `genders` array has a different data structure, you can tell Vuetify what properties to use for the `value` and `text` properties (this is what it looks like you did). So if your genders array looks like this:

```js
const genders = [
  { name: 'male' },
  { name: 'female' },
  { name: 'other' },
]
```

Your `<v-select>` should look like this (in your case you used the SAME property for both text and value, which is perfectly fine to do):

```html
<v-select
  v-model="editedItem.gender"
  :items="genders"
  item-text="name"
  return-object
/>
```

What I'm guessing, based on the image you attached, is that the `genders` array is NOT in one of these formats, and this is causing an error when Vuetify tries to turn it into a dropdown. Also, I think you intend for the value selected to be assigned to `editedItem.gender` and not `editedItem.gender.name`. Here's [a codepen showing how to use objects for `v-select` items](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/yLYgdvm).

If the `items` array is in one of the two formats I showed before, you do NOT need to specify the `item-text` and `item-value` props. They will be detected automatically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate your help to clarify some points:
The matrix of genres is being pulled from the database, and now with the changes, at the time of saving this giving error 500
`Error: "Request failed with status code 500"
    createError createError.js: 16
    settle settle.js: 17
    handleLoad xhr.js: 61
DataTable.vue: 212`

Comment: That means that your API request to create a new user failed. 500 means the error was on the server side. My guess is that the data you sent to the server was not in the format the server was expecting. You either need to alter the data structure being sent, or edit the server side to be able to accept the structure you are sending.

Comment: I'm almost getting the solution, now I'm already managing to save in the database except the genre that is still arriving empty in the database, the information would have to arrive in this format:
`{" id ":" 2 "," firstName ":" Mario "," lastName ":" de Andrade "," phone ":" 1123234454 "," mobilePhone ":" 1123234454 "," email ":" mariodeandrade @ hotmail.com "," gender ": {" name ":" male "}}`

Comment: I believe that I am sinning in this part of the code:
`defaultItem: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        mobilePhone: '',
        gender: '',
      }, `

Would it be this?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using an object to store the gender? Why not just make it a plain text property like first name?

Comment: I could just use the text property, but I will need to insert this type of storage in other parts of the project where there will be association of several tables and consequently I will fall into this problem, so I need to solve it that way

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer. A `v-select` can return the entire object rather than just one of its properties if you set the `return-object` property. See above.

Comment: Still keeps storing empty